# Why doesn't my input onChange work in Edge?

Tags: javascript, input, onchange, microsoft-edge

No error messages, the file gets selected, however the input.onchange = () => {} never gets called.

I added:  to the top of HTML to no result. Any idea why this doesn't work in Edge?

```html
 toolbar.addHandler('image', () => {   
          const range = this.quillReply.getSelection();
          this.selectLocalImage()
         
      })
      toolbar.addHandler('link', (value) => {
          if (value) {
              var href = prompt('Enter the URL');
              this.quillReply.format('link', href);
          } else {
              this.quillReply.format('link', false);
          }
      });
  }
  selectLocalImage = () => {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      input.click();
      // Listen upload local image and save to server
      input.onchange = () => {
      }
}
```

Comment: have you tried the same logic with using [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) instead?

Answer (score 1):

The C should be capitalized in `onChange`.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this question，this code snippets seems to be used in quill editor as a image uploader plugin.

I solved it after change the "selectLocalImage" function to below:

```js
/**
* Select local image
*/
selectLocalImage = () => {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    // do something like upload local image and save to server
  });
  input.click();
}
```

tested in edge 44 and chrome 71.